# Setting Categories using tabs with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, tabs

I would like to ask how to pull categories using tabs. I was able to pull all the items on one tab but I could not pull them per category. here is my code. The data comes from the database and seems to work on All items but I could not figure out how to pull them individually. I need some help with you expertise.

```
           <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">...</div>
       <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="allItems">All Items
      <div>
       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach($items as $per_item)
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <img src="{{$per_item->image_path}}" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <small>{{$per_item->category->name}}</small>
            <h4 class="card-title">
              <a href="/items/{{$per_item->id}}">
              {{$per_item->name}}
              </a>
            </h4> 

            <p class="card-text">{{$per_item->description}}</p>
            <h3>{{$per_item->price}}</h3>

            <form action="/cart/{{$per_item->id}}" method="POST">
              @csrf
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-12 mb-2">
                  <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
     class="w-100"> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-12 mb-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add To 
             Cart</button>      
                </div>

              </div>

            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="consumables">Consumables
  <div>


  </div>


</div>


     <div class="tab-pvane container fade" id="pnuematicTools">Pnuematic 
 Tools</div>
```

Comment: Please include your controller and model that you use on this view.

Comment: sorry I have figured it out, I will update my code